# Why is Mongoose repeating the top-level properties in a document sub-structure?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a Mongoose "user" model defined from a schema which has a substructure, to represent the user's options/preferences.

When I instantiate the model, and inspect it in the Node debugger, it has the top-level user properties like name, email, create_date etc. repeated at every level in the substructure.

In fact it seems to have all properties from the level above, added to each level of substructure. e.g. 'options' is repeated under 'assistants' and 'default'.

The program works OK, because the defined properties at each level are there, but there's just tons of rubbish around it, which makes me worry I've set it up wrong, it's using excess memory, recursing weirdly and might cause strange problems.

e.g. a slightly simplified version:

```
'use strict';
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,                   // full name
    create_date: Date,              // signup date
    email: String,                  // email == username
    password: String,               // hashed password
    options: {
        assistants: {
            default: {
                enabled: Boolean,   // Turn assistant on
            },
        },
    .... (other settings)
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Later I fetch a user by ID:

```
const userModel = require(modelDir+'/user');

userModel.findById(userId (err, user)=>{
    // adjust user.options from GUI input, then re-save
    user.save((err)=>{
        ... etc
    }
}
```

In the node debugger, a User fetched from the DB shows up something like this:

```
user:model
    $__: internalCache{...}
    $init: true
    create_date: (...)
    email: (...)
    errors: undefined
    id: (...)
    isNew: false
    name: (...)
    options: model
        $init: true
        assistants: model
            $init: true
            create_date: undefined
            default: model
                $init: true
                assistants: undefined
                create_date: undefined
                email: undefined
                enabled: false          <= the only real property!
                id: undefined
                name: undefined
                options: undefined
... etc
            email: undefined
            id: undefined
            name: undefined
            options: undefined
            password: undefined
...etc
        $__: internalCache{...}
        $__isNested: true
        email: undefined        <= these ones are greyed-out
        id: undefined
        name: undefined
        options: undefined
        password: undefined
```

If I fetch it from the mongo shell it looks as I'd expect, so it's not to do with how it's saved.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5a6bdbf29c297d0eccb702ec"),
    "name": "Mr Test",
    "email": "...",
    "password": "...",
    "options": {
        "assistants": {
            "default": {
                "enabled": true
            }
        },
    // other stuff removed...
    },
    "__v": 1
}
```

Am I creating the Mongoose schema incorrectly for using a substructure?

```
"mongoose": {
  "version": "4.11.12",

$ mongod --version
db version v3.6.2

$ node -v
v9.4.0
```

Comment: How are you fetching a user? (the line of code)
The `user:model` you posted here seems to be the *Model* and not a specific result.

Comment: I've updated the question - it's via findById.

Answer (score 1):

By default **mongoose** is wrapping results with `MongooseDocuments`. That gives you extra functionality such as the `save()` function you are using. So the extra properties you see aren't coming from your MongoDB server.

> Am I creating the Mongoose schema incorrectly for using a substructure?

From the official [Mongoose schema guide](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#definition), it seems what you are doing is correct.

> Keys may also be assigned nested objects containing further key/type definitions.

And if you want another way to define your schema, there are [Subdocuments](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#).

> Subdocuments are documents embedded in other documents. In Mongoose, this means you can nest schemas in other schemas.

---

To get the raw result from **mongo** you can use the `lean()` method on your query. Unfortunately, it means you won't have the `save()` function and will need to "re-save" in a different way. It is a trade-off between convenience and performance.

The lean operator is nicely explained [in this blog post](http://blog.sandromartis.com/2016/05/08/mongoose-lean/).

And this is from the docs: [Query.protoype.lean()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) (or [Query.lean() in mongoose v4.x](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean))

> Documents returned from queries with the lean option enabled are plain javascript objects, not MongooseDocuments. They have no save method, getters/setters or other Mongoose magic applied.
>
> ...
>
> This is a great option in high-performance read-only scenarios, especially when combined with stream.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the schema properties are repeating at each level?

Comment: As your test with the shell suggests, it is not coming from Mongo. The additional properties you see are part of the `MongooseDocument` wrapper and how mongoose works internally. I can't tell you for sure why it repeats, because that requires diving into `mongoose` code, which I haven't done.
That said, I am unaware of a problem with a schema with document nesting. MongoDB is a document database and does indeed support nested documents. Mongoose as well: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html